# Parsing DTD's using an XML editor

Tags: xml

I am trying to learn XML by reading from W3schools.  I am already at the DTD chapter but I would like to try the samples there.

Thru search here at SO, I found out regarding this free tool XML editor called [Greg XML Editor](http://gregsxmleditor.codeplex.com/)

My problem is that when I tried to include the Document Type Declaration at the xml file.  It is saying **"Validation ERROR: For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD processing set the ProhibitDtd property on XmlReaderSettings to false and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create method."**

I am trying to understand how DTD works but I can seem to test the concept using this tool.  Any idea how to fix this and if there's another xml editor that is free that I can use to handle validation on DTD?

I havent gone thru the XSL/XSD part yet but I am betting that there is  a need for an editor or parser for that also.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That indicates that the author of the software has disabled DTD processing. I notice from the website that it mentions XSD validation but not DTD validation. I assume that you are in a Windows environment as it's a .NET application.

You could try using something like the Personal Edition of the [XMLMind Editor](http://www.xmlmind.com/xmleditor/). That definitely supports DTD validation. XMLMind Editor is java app so will definitely work in your environment and has the advantage of being free whilst XMLSpy is around $400 iirc.

Answer (score 0):

Liquid XML Studo has a [DTD Editor](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/dtd-editor.aspx) that provides syntax highlighting and validation the cheap version is about $99.

[image]